# Adding a Custom Row to Matrix Table - Power Bi - Dax

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax

I'm looking to add some custom rows to a matrix table.

Currently I have been able to produce my data in the following format;

[image]

However I would like to add a custom calculated row which is ratio of the category subtotals.

[image]

However I would like to add a custom calculated row which is ratio of the category subtotals.

Data Model

I have a sales table and a returns table which are both connected to a lookup and calendar table.

[image]

What I've Tried So Far
I tried to use the ammended lookup table and create a measure which contains an if statement - i.e.
if selectedvalue(Subcategory = "Components/Bikes", calculate formula of Components/calculate formula of Bikes) else standard Sales Measure

However the additional rows remained empty.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a solely table as display_table, display_table have three columns [category, subcategory, category_subcategory]. Then add display_table all columns in the matrix table, define two measures. One for normal, the other for special. Using the next dax max:

```
=var m_keyName = Values('display_table'[category_subcategory])
  return 
   if( HASONEVALUE('display_table'[category_subcategory])
  ,if(m_keyName = "Accessories/*",1,0) * [MeasuerONe] 
   + if(m_keyName = "Componnets/*",1,0) * [MeasureTwo]  
  ,[MeasureDefault])
```

Using this pattern, you can control every rows.